# Finding closest previous li

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I'm currently trying to select the previous closest list element within an `<ul>`

My current method works if there is > 1 `<li>` inside of it.

html:

```
<ul id="coaches" class="list">
    <li><span>bob<a class="close"></a></span></li>
    <li class="colored"><span>cobb<a class="close"></a></span></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
    $(this).closest("li").fadeOut("normal", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

How can I make it delete the previous closest list element with both the number of list element = 1 and > 1 elements? I tried adding a prev() and prevAll() chained after `closest('li')` but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you exactly want to delete? I don't get it.

Comment: Is $(this) accessing the <ul> element?

Comment: @BlackDivine I guess `this` refers to one of the `a` elements.

Comment: so .. assuming the event is bound on the `a.close` elements.. if we click on the ***cobb**'s* `.close` link, what should be removed ?

Comment: Your guess is exactly right :D

Comment: @bazmegakapa yes you are correct. and i want to delete the entire `li`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli the `li` that it is in should be removed.

Comment: @bob.. then it should work as you currently have it..

Comment: NOTE: it does NOT work with one element, which is the problem. i know it works by removing the list elements in it's current state (e.g. the code i posted). when it's loaded only with one list element, it won't delete itself when it's clicked.

Comment: @bob.. the provided code should work regardless of the number of elements there are.. the error must lie somewhere else.. (*posted example in my answer..*) (*do you perhaps apply the code to the `.colored` element, and when there is only one there is no element with that class ?*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work as you have it in your example..

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nZXxD/ for the code as it currently is
**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nZXxD/1/ for the code with a single `li` element..

The problem must lie somewhere else..

(*are you sure the event is bound correctly?* and ***after*** the DOM is ready ?)

```
$(function(){
    $('a.close').click(function(){

        $(this).closest("li").fadeOut("normal", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: I think you are probably right. I'll comb through my code. I'm going crazy over here. EDIT: Ok I'm an idiot. I'm dynamically generating list elements that can be added into the unordered list (through an input box elsewhere) and it looks like I was creating invalid html without closing the newer list element.

Comment: @bob, are you changing the DOM dynamically ? *adding / removing* `li` elements ?

Comment: @bob, if you are adding new elements through javascript, you will need to use the `.live` or `.delegate` methods (*for older jQuery versions*), or the `.on()` (*using the selector parameter*) for the 1.7 version..

Answer (score 1):

it just working fine with `prev()`
check the link http://jsfiddle.net/ABqpN/5/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $(this) is referring to the "a" tags inside "span" inside "li", and assuming that when you click on the "a" it's parent "li" should get removed, you can do this:

```
$(this).parent('li').fadeOut("normal", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```